# jquery wookmarks: how to show a loading gif until jquery code has finished running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the jQuery wookmarks plugin from https://github.com/germanysbestkeptsecret/Wookmark-jQuery like this:

```
(function ($) {

  var wookmark;

    wookmark = new Wookmark('.tiles-wrap', {
      offset: 10,
      align: 'center',
      container: $('.results'),
      itemWidth: 300

  });
})(jQuery);
```

The HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="results">
<ul class="tiles-wrap">
<li>...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

While it is loading, I'd like to show a `loading.gif` and not show the `.results` div until the jQuery wookmarks code has finished executing. How would I do that?

Comment: are  you getting event of wookmark start and end ?

Comment: No, I'm running it just like that..?